# Too many Ajax requests causing server failure

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been trying to track down a relatively new problem I have been experiencing. I have a basic table that allows users to drag and drop items into rows. I am using query to cycle through each row and if the item being dropped is not already there I call

```
$.post( "submitassignment.php", {type: assignment[0], id : assignment[1], name: username[1], order: order} );
```

This line will be called anywhere from 10 to 100 times depending on the circumstances. After around the 60th time (not always the same) I start to see in my network panel on chrome Method Post - Status (failed) - Type Pending.

What could be causing this issue?

The full function that is being called when a user drops an item into the table is:

```
function removeAll( item, name ) {
    console.log('remove all');
    assignment = item.attr('id').split('id');
    var all = $('.container:visible')
    all.each(function(){                //remove all only removes visible users
        var fullId = $(this).attr('id').split('id');
        var uId = fullId[1];
        console.log(uId);
        var removedItem = $(this).find('#' + assignment[0] + 'id' + assignment[1] + 'id' + uId);
        if(removedItem.length){
        removedItem.closest('div').removeClass('full');
        removedItem.closest('div').addClass('open');
        removedItem.fadeOut();
        $.post( "removeall.php", {type: assignment[0], id: assignment[1], userId: uId} );
        }
    });     
}
```

The code for the removeall.php file is

```
<?php session_start();
include('../includes/teacherstartup.php');
$type = $_POST['type'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$studentId = $_POST['userId'];
deleteAssignment($studentId, $userGradeLevel, $userSubject, $type, $id);
?>
```

Comment: I went in and completely deleted all the code from removeall.php and the error is still occurring. I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Do you has checked the server error log? Increase the timeout or memory limit... Turn on keep-alive on Apache.. Apparently the requests are piling up, and at some point your server can not respond.

Comment: The memory limit is at 64 MB and the timeout is at 60 seconds. I can not control keep alive. Here is a screenshot of the console log in Chrome.  http://myclassprogress.com/error.png

Comment: you definetly have to check the server-logfile